# Select request keep only above average results

Tags: sql-server-2012

Trying to have a select request work that would select only entries where a certain column's value would be above the average of this said column.

I know I have to use the AVG() function with GROUP BY and HAVING but here's what happens:

```
select ProductName,UnitPrice from products
group by productname,unitprice
having UnitPrice>avg(unitprice)
```

this results me no entries at all.

thought if I use

```
select ProductName,UnitPrice from products
group by productname,unitprice
having UnitPrice>=avg(unitprice)
```

I get a whole bunch of stuff that makes no sense since it's below average (knowing the average is 28,8663).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AVG` over the whole table using `OVER`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            AVG(UnitPrice) OVER() AvgPrice
    FROM products
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE UnitPrice > AvgPrice;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return all rows where UnitPrice is bigger then average price for rows with ProductName:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT  ProductName,
                UnitPrice ,
                AVG(UnitPrice) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductName) Average
        FROM products
    ) t
WHERE UnitPrice > Average;
```